# Is there a way to modify the Blank Jupyter Notebook on VsCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm using the Jupyter Extension from Microsoft in VsCode

Using `Ctrl + Shift + P` in VsCode and

[image: create jupyter blank notebook]

**I would like to modify the blank notebook so it has some pre written cells** like

[image: this]

I googled but haven't found anything

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you  install an extension
[File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brpaz.file-templates)

[image]